# Invoke-Command with script block is not working on remote machine with no error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to call a batch file located in local machine executing the below PowerShell command from remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXXXX -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process "c:\installagent.bat"
} -Credential abc\XXX
```

It's not giving any error but nothing happened on the remote computer.

If I run the batch file from local machine, it's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can't run a local file on a remote host like that. If the account `abc\XXX` has admin privileges on your local computer (and access to the administrative shares is enabled) you could try this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXXXX -ScriptBlock {
  param($myhost)
  Start-Process "\\$myhost\c$\installagent.bat"
} -ArgumentList $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential abc\XXX
```

Otherwise you'll have to copy the script to the remote host first:

```
Copy-Item 'C:\installagent.bat' '\\XXXXXX\C$'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXXXX -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process "c:\installagent.bat"
} -Credential abc\XXX
```

Also, I'd recommend using the call operator (`&`) instead of `Start-Process` for running the batch file:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXXXX -ScriptBlock {
  & "c:\installagent.bat"
} -Credential abc\XXX
```

That way `Invoke-Command` should return the output of the batch file, giving you a better idea of what's going on.

Or, you could simply use [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx):

```
C:\> psexec \\XXXXXX -u abc\XXX -c installagent.bat
```